# Meaning of *light of the view* in "The question makes light of the view presented..."

Tags: phrases

What does the phrase "light of the view mean"?
Context:

> The question makes *light of the view* presented in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You've clipped the phrase in the wrong place. You should be asking, "What does the phrase 'make light of' mean?"

Here is the definition of this idiom according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_light_of):

> To regard without due seriousness; to joke or disregard inappropriately.

So, your given example basically states:

*The question is disregarding or trivializing whatever information is presented in the first paragraph.*

Don't think of the word "light" in this idiom as having to do with the ability to see something, e.g. sunlight or lightbulb. The usage of "light" in "make light of" is related to the definition of being deficient in weight, e.g. "small" or "unserious."

Comment: Welcome. Nice explanation!